# Why does this NamedQuery not work when using an in-memory DB?

Tags: unit-testing, jakarta-ee, jpa, hsqldb

I'm trying to test a stateless session bean with an EntityManager dependency.

This is the persistence unit I create the EntityManager with:

```
<persistence-unit name="ThunderstormTest-PU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
<provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
<class>com.robinfinch.thunderstorm.customer.Customer</class>
<exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
<properties>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:mem:haildb"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.username" value="sa"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value=""/>
  <property name="eclipselink.target-database" value="HSQL"/>
  <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables"/>
  <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINEST"/>  
</properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

This is the NamedQuery:

```
@NamedQuery(
    name="findCustomerWithName",
    query="select c from Customer c where c.name = :custName"
)
```

The problem is that after persisting a Customer,

```
em.find(Customer.class, id)
```

returns the persisted customer, but

```
em.createNamedQuery("findCustomerWithName")
        .setParameter("custName", name)
        .getResultList()
```

doesn't.

The log shows both queries:

```
--Execute query ReadObjectQuery(name="readObject" referenceClass=Customer sql="SELECT ID, NAME FROM CUSTOMER WHERE (ID = ?)")

--Execute query ReadAllQuery(name="findCustomerWithName" referenceClass=Customer sql="SELECT ID, NAME FROM CUSTOMER WHERE (NAME = ?)")
```

When I use a ProgreSQL database, everything works as expected.

Any idea's to what's going on would be much appreciated.

Comment: the query seems to be fine. Are you passing the right values for the name? Just try testing with a LIKE query instead of exact match. Just a thought.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to [flush the entity manager](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#flush%28%29).

`em.find()` will use the cache to find the entity, whereas a query goes straight to the database. Obviously in this case they're out of sync.

I also noticed you're using `RESOURCE_LOCAL` as the transaction type. Are you sure you want to do that? Typically when using JPA in session beans you want `JTA` as the transaction type so that JPA transactions are in sync with EJB transactions. (`RESOURCE_LOCAL` is typically for Java SE apps.) In this case, you can get around the need to flush the entity manager by turning off the cache:

```
<property name="eclipselink.cache.shared.default" value="false"/>
```

Comment: Thanks Steve, you put me on the right path. For the test I use RESOURCE_LOCAL because I'm running the session bean outside the container, the real thing uses a persistence unit with transaction type JTA. The problem was solved by begin'ning and commit'ting a transaction before and after each test.